# Nim: aliasing procedures with side effects

Tags: function-pointers, side-effects, nim-lang

I am trying to create a pointer to a procedure (or equivalent). When I do something like this:

```
import random

# maybe a command line argument
let choice = "some algorithm"

proc withoutSideEffects(): int = 0
proc withSideEffects(): int = rand(10)

let procPtr =
  case choice
  of "algorithm1": withoutSideEffects
  of "algorithm2": withSideEffects
  (...)
```

the compiler complains, demanding that all procedures in the case expression must have the pragma {.noSideEffects.}

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way around this?
2. If not, is this intentional (maybe for discouraging bad design)?
3. What are the alternatives?

Comment: The problem seems to be in that the compiler is deducting variable type from the first branch. If you swap the branches, it works just fine as proc{.noSideEffects,gcsafe.} can be converted to proc{.gcsafe.}.

Comment: I'm not sure, however, how to explicitly mark procPtr as having side effects which would be the proper solution.

Comment: I see. I am glad that at least there is a solution (which s also not too inconvenient). Thank you!

Comment: I have opened this as an issue on https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/12642.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to replace the *expression* form (which infers its return type from the first branch) with the *statement* form (one which doesn't have a return type)

The same problem, and same solution exists for if/then expressions

```
let procPtr = block:
  var result:proc():int
  case choice
  of "algorithm1": result = withoutSideEffects
  of "algorithm2": result = withSideEffects
  else: discard
  result
```